# Javascript form redirect (with variable)

Tags: javascript, variables, redirect

I need help getting started this may be tricky.

I want a javascript whereby it allows you to enter a variable. (For instance, a name)and for whatever name is entered, it redirects you to a page (based on the variable entered).

The website would be pretty blank, and have the question.

"What is your name?"

They'd enter their name, hit enter / submit - and it'll redirect them to the page, specific to their name.

Ideas?

Comment: Setting to `document.location` URL you need will make browser get to that another URL.

Comment: I'm not following, sorry ?

Answer (score 0):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location
>
> JavaScript `document.location` property allows you to load another
>   URL.

```
var name = 'John';
document.location = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + name;
```

This code sets name `John` to the local variable `name`. Then it changes current `document.location` to `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John` what leads to loading that URL in current tab of the browser (or window).